# absolute beginner to integration, need to study integration for highschool level competition exam

Tags: integration

I'm in high school and lazed around during 1months class of integration, mainly because my teachers were only focused on getting students to memorize types and solve questions based on them. I can memorize types but really dislike memorizing stuff. I'm really good at differentiation(for my course level). Differentiation follows rule and such and hence it is easy to get creative with it and solve even more complex question.
I want to know if there are stead fast rules to solving integration or atleast some vital points to note while solving one. I dont mind memorizing formulae and type but it becomes tedious when there is a different type for each question you get.
Is integration really only about memorizing stuff, or is there pattern recognition and rules at play?

Comment: Didn't you have to memorize the rules for differentiation? Computing the anti-derivative is simply finding the inverse: what function would I take the derivative of to get "this". Yes, that can be difficult to do and for some things there is no way to solve algebraically.

Comment: My tried and true method of learning math is to attack many math exercises.

Comment: so is memorizing types the only way of solving questions?

Comment: In addition to treating integration as anti-differentiation as a form of pattern recognition, it is worth being able to handle partial fractions, integration by parts, and substitution, and to know how to deal with $\int \frac1x\, dx$.

Comment: @user2661923 is there any source you'd recommend to do questions from?

Comment: That is a question for your math teachers.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who are more experienced users, I'm sorry, I just don't have enough reputation to comment. Anyways it's more pattern-y than memorization. Patterns like substitution, integration by parts, and partial fractions are going to be a lot more helpful than memorizing an integral table. I would highly recommend checking out blackpenredpen's many videos on integration and practicing on the examples he provides.